# How can I disable the Windows 7 taskbar?

Tags: windows-7, windows, taskbar

I am not talking about hiding it. I am talking about disabling it - making it completely disappear. We have a kiosk-software that is very nice, but due to a problem this software has, the taskbar is not being disabled. So I need to find another way to disable it myself.

Perhaps it can be brought back by some keyboard command.. Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [Aviassin Taskbar Eliminator](http://www.aviassin.com/taskbareliminator) is a
>   great utility which will simply and
>   efficiently remove the taskbar from
>   Windows XP, Windows Vista, or Windows
>   7.
>
> With just the click of a button or a
>   hotkey, the taskbar is disabled from
>   any side of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

If your are using a Professional edition I would use the Group Policy Editor that is included with Windows. Some times third party solutions disable them using undocumented or incomplete. Type `gpedit.msc` in the Start Menu for lauching it.

With that tool you can disable almost anything from the Desktop, Start Menu and My PC (regular folders and special ones like the Control panel).