# Windows 7 taskbar is hidden but still docked

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

I want to reclaim the space taken by the taskbar and also hide it (not visible at all, ever), however I still need to be able to access the Start menu via Ctrl-Esc (Windows key is disabled on this machine).  I have tackled the hiding part, but now when I maximize a window, I can see the desktop at the bottom where the taskbar would normally be.  (Imagine the taskbar rendered as completely transparent and non-mouse-interactive.)

I tried setting the taskbar to auto-hide, which reclaims the space, but that makes it visible, undoing my other settings.

Is there a way to set up the taskbar to remain invisible ("not rendered") and allow maximized applications to use the space?  I'm open to registry edits, programmatic solutions, and just about anything else, but **third-party apps are not allowed**.

Alternatively, is there another way to access the Start menu without the taskbar?  If so, can I have explorer.exe run without showing the taskbar?

Comment: The windows key will popup the start menu ...

Comment: @DavidPostill, that's only if the taskbar is present (which is only when explorer is running).  I'm trying to find a way to make the taskbar disappear and reclaim the space it occupies.

Comment: Hmm. I just set my taskbar to auto hide and maximised a window (which occupies the whole screen). The windows key displays the start menu as expected ...

Comment: @DavidPostill, yes, but the taskbar is still visible (e.g. when you press the windows key).  I need a solution that doesn't render the taskbar at all.

Comment: You are writing as if the hide function isn't working.. but you want to completely hide or remove the taskbar.  This might help. http://superuser.com/questions/382127/windows-7-task-bar-at-autohide-make-it-totally-disapear   also consider shortening the vertical height to next to nothing