# kill explorer.exe for Windows 7 for kiosk for school student to use

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, taskbar, hide

Sorry, our school still using windows 7, I am running a simple flash application and auto shutdown in task scheduler for my windows 7.

I tried afew of Hide Taskbar Application but some how the taskbar sometime still show on top of my application.

I had searched that the only way is do it is to "kill explorer.exe repalce shell", but i can't find any tutorial to do that. anyone know any tutorial can link me or explain to me how should i start?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Typically, you can temporarily kill Explorer (`explorer.exe`) with a simple `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `Delete` and shut any instances down like any normal process (I assume you are an administrator). Regarding replacing Explorer, [Wikipedia has a list of alternative shells for Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_alternative_shells_for_Windows), so it might be worth researching those then trying to find a tutorial for the shell you wish to use.

Answer (score 1):

You may kill Explorer with this command:

```
taskkill /f /im explorer.exe
```

Useful references:

- [Windows 7 task bar at autohide, make it totally disappear?](https://superuser.com/questions/382127/windows-7-task-bar-at-autohide-make-it-totally-disapear)
- [Windows 7 kiosk mode](https://sites.google.com/site/mblyamaha/home/client-setting/windows/7/windows-7-kiosk-mode)
- [Reboot Restore Rx Freeware version](https://horizondatasys.com/reboot-restore-rx-freeware/)